# Using PHP to create hierarchy list from flat array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array element values that need to be converted from the line-by-line example to a more hierarchical approach.

From this:

(a)
(b)
(1)
(2)
(i)
(ii)
(3)
(4)
(c)
(d)
(1)

To the following:

(a)
(b)
(b)(1)
(b)(2)
(b)(2)(i)
(b)(2)(ii)
(b)(3)
(b)(4)
(c)
(d)
(d)(1)

(a) is the top level, numerical values are the second level, and Roman numbers are the third level.

The structured source isn't something we can control. We receive the data and need to reformat it to the desired format.

I have tried several loops/ifs/while, etc, but can't achieve the result.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The app uses PHP, but I haven't found any solutions.

Tried this already

```
$elements = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'i', 'ii', '3', '4', 'c', 'd', '1'];
    $newElements = [];
    $currentMain = '';

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if (ctype_alpha($element)) {
            $currentMain = $element;
            $newElements[] = $element;
        } elseif (is_numeric($element)) {
            $newElements[] = $currentMain . '(' . $element . ')';
        } else {
            $newElements[] = $currentMain . '(' . end($newElements) . ')' . '(' . $element . ')';
        }
    }

    print_r($newElements);
```

and produces the following:

Array
(
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => b(1)
[3] => b(2)
[4] => i
[5] => ii
[6] => ii(3)
[7] => ii(4)
[8] => c
[9] => d
[10] => d(1)
)

Comment: Please explain the rules for conversion.

Comment: "I have tried several loops" ... Only one loop is needed for this. Thats the hint.

Comment: I agree that the rules are not clear. What would the sequence `(g)(h)(1)(i)(j)` convert to? This sound a bit a like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). How did you get into the situation in the first place?

Comment: The rules appear to be a nested "ordered list". Lower case letters are top-level. Digits are nested next. Roman numerals are nested after that.

Comment: @getSet I think we all get that, but there are problem with that that haven't been addressed.

Comment: Agreed the rules on face are readily apparent. Not seeing whats problematic though.

Comment: I just updated the request, I hope this helps.  The structured source isn't something we can control.  We receive the data and need to reformat it to the desired format.  (a) is the top level, numerical values are the second level, and Roman numbers are the third level.

Comment: Your question was closed by a mod due to lack of clarity (at the time). ... From looking at your newly posted code, I can see that you did attempt it (put effort in). Could you reopen this question with all of the detail that you show here, so that it now gets the due answers desired?

Comment: As I pointed out in my first comment here, this question can currently not be solved. Can you address the problem of the `(g)(h)(1)(i)(j)` sequence? Do you understand this problem? Note that `(i)` can either indicate a top level element or a third level element and there's no way to tell which one it is. You need to define a strict rule for that. For instance: The first level can only go up to the letter `(h)`. A similar restriction should be in place for the third level.